# How to automate unlock pattern on a real phone using uiautomator?

Tags: android, automation, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I have recently started learning `uiautomator` for the UI testing of various Android devices. Currently I am testing on Galaxy S4.

I am looking for any class or method which can be used to automate the unlock pattern that user draws to unlock the phone. For example, I have letter `N` as a "draw pattern" to unlock the phone. How can I automate this unlock pattern in `uiautomator`?

Comment: Is unlocking part of your test? If its not, it will be easier to just unlock it, then run your test.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have letter "N" as unlock pattern, then first you have find the co-ordinates of each point of that N shape in your device. As you mentioned, the entire pattern lock will have 9 dots, you have to get (x,y) co-ordinates of 4 dots. To get the co-ordinates, you can use the 
same method mentioned earlier in one of the answer.

1. Go to 'Settings' -> 'Developer Options'.
2. Under 'INPUT' section -> you will find a option 'Pointer Location' -> enable that option.

Once you get your 4 dots' co-ordinates, use **swipe(Point[] segments, int segmentSteps)** method of UiAutomator Framework.

The input for this method is the 4 set of co-ordinates that you got from your device screen as Point array. This will give continuous swipe through the points.

I have given a sample script below for your understanding.

```
import android.graphics.Point;

public void unlockpatternlock() throws UiObjectNotFoundException, Exception {
    Point[] cordinates = new Point[4];
    cordinates[0] = new Point(248,1520);
    cordinates[1] = new Point(248,929);
    cordinates[2] = new Point(796,1520);
    cordinates[3] = new Point(796,929);
    getUiDevice().wakeUp();
    getUiDevice().swipe(cordinates, 10);
}
```

Above script would draw N shape smoothly. Remember input the co-ordinates according to your device screen.

Comment: This is a great answer. It also helped me with drawing a shape using uiautomator

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#swipe%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) is the only way I know to do it, but it can be tedious trying to find your x and y coordinates.

```
UiDevice.getInstance().swipe(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY, int steps)
```

The only probelm I see is to do an "N", you would need 3 of these `swipe`'s. To unlock, it needs to be one continuous swipe.

Give it a show. Finding your x and y will be tough. I would go to my "apps home" page and look at apps (with the `uiautomatorviewer`) that are in relatively the same spot, find their coords, then go from there.

**NOTE** The `int steps` is how fast and "smooth" you want to swipe. I like to use 5 or 10. It seems pretty natural.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, the uiautomatorviwer tool does not provide exact co-ordinates for the dots. The tool just provides details of the entire box control containing 9 dots. I was looking for any inbuilt method which would just make a pattern if user provided the start and end points.

Comment: Thats why I am saying it will be tedious trying to find your coords. So open your uiviewer, go to your apps page, and look at the apps that are close to the same position as your "dots", and retrieve bounds from them. And work from that. There is no built in method to unlock patterns. This would be the only way with uiautomator

Answer (score 1):

To find out the co-ordinates of the screen , you can follow this :

```
[1] Go to 'Settings' -> 'Developer Options'.
[2] Under 'INPUT' section -> you will find a option 'Pointer Location' -> enable that option.
```

After that if you touch anywhere on the screen -> you can view the exact screen coordinates of that point on top of the screen on your device.

And after you get the coordinates , you can use swipe method say like this  -

```
UiDevice.getInstance().swipe(390, 1138, 719, 1128, 40);
```

method easily giving the exact co-ordinates where to drag from and till what point.

I have already used this and it works!

Comment: copy from: http://www.coderexception.com/CHbzHuuNPWXPWUJS/how-to-automate-unlock-pattern-on-a-real-phone-using-uiautomator